# Stuck Threads in the application using Spring and EclipseLink JPA

Tags: spring, performance, jpa, oracle11g

Stuck Threads are coming in the application using Spring, EclipseLink JPA and deployed in weblogic.

These stuck threads are coming only during the load test of the application and that to in endurance tests. In one hour or two hour load tests everything is fine and there are no stuck threads in the application.

Here i'm attaching the log for two of the stuck threads,

```
Thread1:
####<Apr 16, 2014 1:19:34 AM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <esxsrv12s1> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '23' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1397591374727> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '32' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "644" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 644406 ms
", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
    java.lang.Throwable.getStackTraceElement(Native Method)
    java.lang.System$2.getStackTraceElement(System.java:1153)
    java.util.logging.LogRecord.inferCaller(LogRecord.java:490)
    java.util.logging.LogRecord.getSourceClassName(LogRecord.java:259)
    org.eclipse.persistence.logging.LogFormatter.format(LogFormatter.java:64)
    com.myapp.common.logging.CustomAbstractSessionLog.computeMessage(CustomAbstractSessionLog.java:74)
    com.myapp.common.logging.CustomAbstractSessionLog.internalLog(CustomAbstractSessionLog.java:56)
    com.myapp.common.logging.CustomAbstractSessionLog.log(CustomAbstractSessionLog.java:30)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:3100)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4218)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4190)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4166)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4063)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1148)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:84)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:456)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy103.getLetters(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor998.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)


Thread2: 

####<Apr 16, 2014 1:49:06 AM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <esxsrv12s1> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '90' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1397593146086> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '41' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "637" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 1, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 637469 ms
", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
    org.eclipse.persistence.logging.LogFormatter.format(LogFormatter.java:45)
    com.myapp.common.logging.CustomAbstractSessionLog.computeMessage(CustomAbstractSessionLog.java:74)
    com.myapp.common.logging.CustomAbstractSessionLog.internalLog(CustomAbstractSessionLog.java:56)
    com.myapp..common.logging.CustomAbstractSessionLog.log(CustomAbstractSessionLog.java:30)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:3100)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4218)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4190)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ExternalConnectionPool.releaseConnection(ExternalConnectionPool.java:97)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:581)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:207)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:646)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2611)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2570)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:420)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1081)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1128)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:742)
```

We have checked the Database and there were no locks in DB. There were no long running queries. Max DB CPU and memory usage is also not beyond 40%.

What could be the issue here, Please help me out in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We had a lot of problems with stuck threads.  You might find this link helpful:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_diagnose_and_resolve_hangs_and_deadlocks.3F

We found that stuck threads were unrelated to database deadlocks.  Essentially the EclipseLink cache was deadlocking on cache access, as one thread would fail to release a lock and another thread would ask for the object that is locked.

The stuck thread max time (in your example 600 seconds) is usually a configurable parameter in your J2EE container. In our experience there was no benefit to increasing or decreasing this number since once the thread was stuck it was stuck until killed by the container.

What finally resolved the issue for us was to make all of our @ManyToOne relationships FetchType.LAZY.  This carries a performance penalty since all of these queries then require additional additional SQL queries but it was the only thing we found that resolved the issues.  You should try the other suggestions in that link and see if they work for you.

More information here:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1108983/#msg_1108983